# Once approver approved infopath form, email is not triggered to requester

Tags: workflow, infopath, email, approval-process

I have created a simple InfoPath leave request form. There is a field/column called status. If superior approved/rejected the form, then it will update the field accordingly. However, when I used it in the workflow, it seems it didn't hit the step (I highlighted on workflow picture below).

[image: WORKFLOW]

[image: InfoPath Form]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I already solved the problem.

1) I need to check "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed"

2) To avoid email repetition, I need to amend the workflow:

[image]